# How to sort or order date in dynamic Pivot Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> I have the following table

[image]

The table after pivoting is as follows. How do I maintain the date order in pivoted columns?

[image]

Comment: your sql statemnets? please share

Comment: It depends on how you pivot data. In any case, at some point you should sort/order DATE values as `datetime`/`date`. I think at this moment the values of DATE column are `strings`/`varchar`.

Comment: The date is getting ordered with your query, but how to bring in the same format with slash 01/jan/2014 etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my own way to resolve this problem

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (Name varchar(10), [DATE] datetime, Value int)
INSERT #TEMP VALUES 
('A','01/JAN/2014',10), 
('B','01/JAN/2014',20), 
('A','26/JAN/2014',20), 
('B','26/JAN/2014',30), 
('A','01/FEB/2014',40), 
('B','01/FEB/2014',50), 
('A','26/FEB/2014',60),
('B','26/FEB/2014',70)
```

Now we assign date in the format **DD/MMM/YYYY** to the variable
(Note: The [DATE] column should be of the type datetime/date)

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106), ' ', '/') + ']', 
               '[' + REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106), ' ', '/') + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM #TEMP) PV  
               ORDER BY [DATE]
```

After pivot the columns will be in perfect Date order with the format **DD/MMM/YYYY**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT Name,REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106), '' '', ''/'') [DATE] , value FROM #TEMP
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM(value)
                 FOR [DATE] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Like this you can convert to any date formats and can maintain the order of date in pivoted columns
by editing the conversion type in `SELECT @cols` and inner `SELECT` of Pivot statement

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it dynamically.

```
    CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  NAME VARCHAR(10),
  DATECOL DATE,
  VALUECol INT   
)

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES
('A', '01/JAN/2014', 10),
('B', '01/JAN/2014', 20),
('A', '26/JAN/2014', 20),
('B', '26/JAN/2014', 30),
('A', '01/FEB/2014', 40),
('B', '01/FEB/2014', 50),
('A', '26/FEB/2014', 60),
('B', '26/FEB/2014', 70)


 DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DATECOL) 
                    from TEST
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select NAME,DATECOL,VALUECOL
        from TEST

      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(VALUECOL)
        for DATECOL in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

    exec(@query)
```

Check this on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86fce/3)